# How to filter some path from gorilla mux.Router

Tags: go, routes, gorilla

I would like to match only some routes from a mux.Router, and use the same handler for all the others. How can I do this?

i.e.: having these paths:

```
/general/baz/bro
/general/foo/bar
/general/unknown
```

I would like to match the first with a specific handler, and all the others with a default handler.

I've tried with no success something like:

```
r.Methods("GET").PathPrefix("/general").Handler(defaultHandler)
r.Methods("GET").Path("/general/baz/bro").Handler(bazBroHandler)
```

I was expecting the bazBroHandler handling the `/general/baz/bro` path, and the defaultHandler all the other starting with `/general`

Comment: You can try regexp. I suppose, it is not ideomatic way, but it probably could help:
   `get := repo.Methods("GET").Subrouter()`
   `get.Handle("/general/baz/bro", bazBroHandler)`
   `get.Handle("/general/{unknown:[0-9A-Za-z]+}", defaultHandler)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I've just realized that I needed to invert the order:

```
r.Methods("GET").Path("/general/baz/bro").Handler(bazBroHandler)
r.Methods("GET").PathPrefix("/general").Handler(defaultHandler)
```

now everything is working!

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is by using [MatcherFunc](https://godoc.org/github.com/gorilla/mux#Router.MatcherFunc). In the `MatcherFunc`, compare/verify the incoming request `Path`, i.e.:

```
//Default handler
r.MatcherFunc(func(r *http.Request, rm *mux.RouteMatch) bool {
    return r.URL.Path != "/general/baz/bro" && strings.HasPrefix(r.URL.Path, "/general") && r.Method == "GET"
}).Handler(defaultHandler)

//Specific handler
r.Methods("GET").Path("/general/baz/bro").Handler(bazBroHandler)
```